# All the requests in a postman collection do not run

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner, postman-pre-request-script

I am new to postman. I have 6 requests collection and I am using variables that pass from these requests.

In request 3 I am using the If else statement and postman.setNextRequest to ensure that the request goes in loop until I get the required parameters, once I get the parameters I should run the next request which is mentioned in the else statement.

The request in the else statement does not seem to run when I run the collection. In the collection runner I do not see any error either. After request 3 runs, request 4, 5 and 6 should run.

When I run requests 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 individually, all of them work as expected. When I run them as a collection It executes until request 3 which is in loop and the request 4, 5, 6 do not run.

Please help me understand how I can fix this issue. Please check the code below -

Request 3: i.e  "Get Dataflow Execution Time 2"

```
bodyData = JSON.parse(responseBody);

if (responseCode.code === 200 && bodyData.dataflowJobs[0].status !== "Success" && bodyData.dataflowJobs[0].label === "MyOpps_Data_Dataflow") {

// Request 3 which is in loop until I get the status === "success"
  postman.setNextRequest("Get Dataflow Execution Time 2"); 
} else {

  postman.setNextRequest("Schedule Recipe"); // Request 4
  var current_timestamp = new Date();
  console.log(current_timestamp.toISOString())
}
```

Comment: Can you confirm that each request in the collection has no unsaved changes? The request tabs should have no orange dots on them.

Comment: Thanks for checking this Danny. There are no unsaved changes.

Comment: Are there more details about the response bodies that meet those conditions? Anything that gives others the ability to run this locally? Without that it's a lot of words and a small piece of code from the test tab 

Comment: Sorry, there was some issue with the name of the next script. It is working now. Thank you Danny